# How can I see the error log when I run wearable wgt through gear manager?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I ran my android app(which includes a wearable wgt) on my Samsung S4. It also installed the wgt to my Samsung Gear 2 using Gear Manager. How can I check the error log of my wgt on my Samsung Gear 2?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Terminal or Command prompt, you can run following commands to get the logs

```
sdb shell dlogutil
```

to get all logs on the gear.

To clear logs use `sdb shell dlogutil -c`

To get specific logs, you can run `sdb shell dlogutil | grep -i YourTextThatYouWantToSearch` basically pipe grep with prev command.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79894/discussion-on-answer-by-srkushwaha-how-can-i-see-the-error-log-when-i-run-wearab).

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing to a system log or a file in your private data space? Have you tried connecting the watch to your computer and using the Tizen IDE to look in /var/log? I was able to pull the logs using the Connection Manager. Or from a command line with

```
sdb shell
```

Comment: My devices are both connected to my computer, when i ran my android app in eclipse which automatically installed the wgt. I opened the wgt and nothing was showing in my Tizen IDE